# What does その正体に注目 mean in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning

I was watching the news > [link](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5jzoqy) and I think the MC said

at 1:23

> 先週オープンしたアミューズメントパーク「トンデミ」大人も子供も汗だくで楽しめる**その正体に注目**

According to Jishou, 正体 = true character; true form; true colors; true colours; identity​. 
Thus I was confused how to translate this.

Answer (score 1):

The announcer is essentially saying, "Let's take a look at the nature [of this place]."  In more colloquial English we'd say, "Let's see what this place is like."

Comment: 「注目」 is far more nuanced than just "take a look" or "see what it's like".

Comment: @l'électeur feel free to edit my response.

Comment: 「注目」 might be as nuanced as "observe", but colloquially speaking the phrase as a newscaster would use is as you've already said so I don't think there's a need to edit, though l'électeur is correct that the word doesn't simply mean to "take a look"

Answer (score 0):

My translation would go like this:

The eye-catching characteristic features of the amusement park "Tondemi" opened last week where both adults and children can play in sweaty fun.

OR

The amusement park "Tondemi" just opened last week where both adults and children can play in sweaty fun.   Its characteristic features are eye-catching